# FATAL EXCEPTION : main Can you Help me?

Tags: android

I wanna add tabs to content main ! I have problems with the code ! There is my XML code for content_main ! the message error says :

```
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and there is my MainActivity code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TabActivityLayout tabActivityLayout=new TabActivityLayout();
    tabActivityLayout.setContentView(R.layout.content_main);



    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {



    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

} >
 and the TabActivityLayout code :

```
    public class TabActivityLayout extends TabActivity {
    private TabHost mTabHost;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    mTabHost =getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    // Francai sTab
    intent = new Intent(this,FrancaisActivity.class);
     spec =mTabHost.newTabSpec("Francais")
             .setIndicator("Francais")
             .setContent(intent);

    // Anglais Tab
            intent = new Intent(this,AnglaisActivity.class);
    spec =mTabHost.newTabSpec("Anglais")
            .setIndicator("Anglais")
            .setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Arabe Tab
            intent = new Intent(this,ArabeActivity.class);
    spec =mTabHost.newTabSpec("Arabe")
            .setIndicator("Arabe")
            .setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);

   mTabHost.setCurrentTab(2);

}
```

}

Comment: Please post the exception + full stacktrace + the line it got triggered from

Answer (score 0):

The following code is throwing the fatal exception:

```
TabActivityLayout tabActivityLayout=new TabActivityLayout();
tabActivityLayout.setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
```

You should not set the contentView from another activity, `setContentView()` will be called in the activity `onCreate()` method.

Also one more suggestion, The following line is repeated 3 times:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

If you needed to access that view outside of onCreate() then it needs to be declared as a field:

```
private DrawerLayout drawer;
```

then set initialize it only once, right after `setContentView()` like you did with the other view:

```
drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Comment: Not going to be the cause of any exception though is it? and "If you needed to access that view outside of onCreate() then it needs to be declared as a field" isn't true.

Comment: @weston you have a valid point, I am just trying to help though, just expanded on my answer